# What Is a Class? Oracle Java tutorial, bicycle class example

Tags: java, class

In the tutorial, there are 2 pieces of code, not sure if they are trying to explain 2 different things or are the 2 pieces of code suppose to connect to each other.
Here is the first one defining the class:

```
class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
}
```

Here is the second piece of code where they create 2 objects:

```
class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

How would I piece these two together? Would the code below be the correct way? If so, why is it correct? Won't it also duplicate the main class for each object and cause the program to crash if called? (Obviously I can just not call the "main" function explicitly)

```
package classes;

class Bicycle {
    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;
    
    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
        cadence = newValue;
    }
    
    void changeGear(int newValue) {
        gear = newValue;
    }
    
    void speedUp(int increment) {
        speed = speed + increment;
    }
    
    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
        speed = speed - decrement;
    }
    
    void printStates() {
        System.out.println("cadence:" + cadence + " speed:" + speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();
        
        bike1.printStates();
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Won't it also duplicate the main class for each object and cause the program to crash if called?"*  ... This sentence makes no sense to me. Why would it duplicate a __class__ for each __object__? ... *"Obviously I can just not call the "main" function explicitly"* ... You can't? That sentence is wrong, so I wonder why you wrote "obviously".

Comment: I think they are concerned that creating multiple instances of the `Bicycle` class will create multiple copies of the `main` method and will thus cause the program to fail if they tried to call `main` in their code. Of course, that is not actually true since methods are loaded once and then shared between instances.

Comment: One *class* can have multiple *instances*. Human is a class. Laurel and Hardy refer to two different instances of that class. Bicycle is a class. Your variables `bike1` and `bike2` refer to two different instances.

Answer (score 1):

There are two classes, just to keep *what a class does* and *how to use a class* separate.

`Bicycle` is the primary focus: it shows you how a single class is defined, what its fields and methods are and how those things interact.

`BicycleDemo` is nothing more than a container for a `main` method. This `main` method is the primary entry point of a Java program. Since `main` is (by definition) always `static` it does not require an instance of `BicycleDemo` to exist and none is instantiated unless you explicitly do so somewhere in your code. This class only exists because Java doesn't have "free functions" that are not associated to any type. All methods need to be associated to a type (class/interface/...).

The `main` method here is used to demonstrate how to *use* a class, i.e. it instantiates two instances of `Bicycle` and interacts with them to demonstrate how a class would be used.

Note that in general it is *good practice* (but not technically necessary) to put the `main` method in a class that does nothing else. Since the `main` method is special (since it's the one that's called when starting an application), it makes sense to put it into its own dedicated place.

Your "merged" `Bicycle` class works just fine: you simply moved the `main` method out of the `BicycleDemo` and put it into `Bicycle` which doesn't fundamentally change anything about either the `Bicycle` class or the `main` method.

But the two separate classes would work fine as well: executing `java BicycleDemo` (when both classes have been compiled and the classpath is set up correctly) will execute `BicycleDemo.main`, which will in turn instantiate the `Bicycle` objects and call those methods on them.